# EFFECT any player under a specific height anywhere in world?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So here goes my first question:
I am simply trying to affect every player on my server below y=57 with glowing. This seems like an easy task but I can only get it to work within a range. I need this to work across the whole world. For some reason or another, this command will not do the trick:

```
execute as @a run effect give @s[y=0,dy=57] minecraft:glowing 3 1
```

This, in theory, should make all players affect themselves with glowing if they are between y=0 and y=57. What this DOES do is give any player with the same x and z cords as the command block (Always active, Repeat) glowing, but not if they are not in the same y axis as it. I'm confused, so please, if you find something from the many weird half-done forums, let me know.

EDIT: I HAD IT... for a second. I did:

```
/execute as @a[x=29999984,dx=-29999984,z=29999984,dz=-29999984,y=0,dy=57] run effect give @s minecraft:glowing 3 1
```

but as soon as it started working, it stopped again, and not the command block will not run it anymore. I tried lowering the numbers that are 29999984 to 1000000 to see if the other numbers lagged it out, but it still didn't work. The command block does not even show an output, yet it is on always active and repeat. Even setting it to 100 didn't work, not even 10. no matter what I try, the command is broken now!

`IS THIS EVEN POSSIBLE?`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`as` doesn't shift the execution position, so you're still executing from the command block's position. You just need to add `at @s`:

```
execute as @a at @s run effect give @s[y=0,dy=57] minecraft:glowing 3 1
```

Also, in theory this should work, without `execute`:

```
effect give @a[x=-30000000,dx=60000000,y=0,dy=57,z=-30000000,dz=60000000] glowing 3 1
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked perfectly!

Comment: I just noticed that you don't even need `as` if you're using `execute`, so you could have just changed the `s` to a `t` to fix it.

Comment: XD 1.13 commands are just too different from what I'm used to in 1.12